# Is there any way to see estimated Azure costs before actually using the services?

Tags: azure

Right now I have a small web app hosted on Azure services. Its 5 asp.net pages, 1 sql DB, and 2 scheduled jobs. Just through testing, I used 2 dollars of the 220 dollars credit they give you for signing up.

The problem I'm having is that there is no clear pricing guide for the pay-as-you-go service they offer. My live testing was very very lightweight (10 page hits, maybe 50db transactions, and 10 job runs) and its already cost 2 dollars. The breakdown available makes it clear where that money has gone (the scheduled jobs), but doesnt make it clear how much additional usage may cost me going forward.

Is there any area in azure, or any service anywhere, that can estimate the total cost under various loads? I am very hesitant to open this service up to the public until I know exactly what the costs will be, as right now the site brings in 0 revenue, so it wouldnt be worth paying a ton of money just for hosting until I get a revenue model set up.

Comment: Since Azure pricing is based on consumption (i.e. the resources you as a customer consume) and not by the load on your application, you may need to change your evaluation criteria. Check out Azure pricing calculator here: http://azure.microsoft.com.

Comment: *edit* never mind, I always thought those bars were based on your current usage (since they start at the current base usage). I didnt realise those were sliders. Awesome, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure - use the Azure pricing calculator - http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/